# Actionscript 3 unstable framerate

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, lag, frame-rate

I'm trying to develop a game in Actionscript 3, but sudden and frequent lagspikes make the game very uncomfortable to play.

Currently the entire game is simply moving a square, so there are no heavy calculations that should cause this.

I have tried using both Timer and Enter_Frame events. They both are pretty unstable. I have also tried different framerates.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

```
//var timer = new Timer;
//timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, time);
//timer.start();
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, time);

function time(evt:Event):void
{
        now=(getTimer());
        dt = now-then;
        trace(dt);
        then = now;
}
```

Gives following output (attempted FPS: 100):

3 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 11 **30 56 49** 5 10 11 10 11 8 11 10 9 11 9 11 10 10 10 10 9 10 10 10 14 7 9 14 6 10 10 11 9 10 10 11 9 10 10 11 10 9 11 9 10 10 11 9 11 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 **29** 7 5 5 14 4 6 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 11 10 10 9 12 8 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 12 8 9 11 10 10 9 11 10 10 11 10 9 10 10 11 10 9 10 11 10 10 9 11 10 10 10 10 10 9 11 10 10 9 11 10 9 10 10 11 9 10 10 10 10 11 9 10 11 9 11 9 10 **31** 6 5 4 6 8 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 11 11 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 9 10 10 11 9 10 11 9 10 11 9 10 10 10 9 11 14 6 9 10 11 10 11 10 9 10 11 10 9 11 9 15 5 11 **35** 15 **42 64 37** 15 6 5 10 11 9 10 11 9 10 11 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 **28** **63 65 63** 8 15 **56 57** 13 6 13 12 6 11 **36 69 20 25** 12 6 6 5 5 **33 36 57 20 34 21** 12 9 13 6 6 5 9 6 9 7 7 10 10 10 11 10 10 10 10

**I have uploaded a swf to demonstrate the problem (60 FPS here).** [Here is the link.](http://www.filedropper.com/alpha_2) (move with keys). As you will experience, the square moves smoothly for most of the time, but frequent lagspikes makes it uncomfortable.

**EDIT:** It seems like the application runs much smoother when all the code is in the FLA timeline compared to when most of it is in different AS files. Any possible reason for that?

Comment: It's hard to say without seen the code....

Comment: It's not the code that leads to this..but i can show you anyway.

Comment: What is `getTimer()` doing?  Also, do you notice the same behavior if you export a release swf?

Comment: show `getTimer()` function.

Comment: @Fergoso: [it's a top level function documented here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29)

Comment: The code you posted produces that output?

Comment: @Aaron, yes with " " being "\n".

Comment: Ok. I asked because you mention a square being moved around, but that code does not do that. I tried it and did not see the same results.

Comment: Its just basic Keyboard listeners and a sprite moving around. I removed it because it's not relevant. The framerate is as unstable with that as without.

Comment: It might be relevant... if you take it all out, so that the code you posted is all you have, do you still get the output you posted?

Comment: Another important question: how are you playing the SWF?

Comment: @Aaron I hit CtRL + SHIFT + Enter in Flash Professional.

Comment: He's likely creating a bunch of new instance of something and the lag spikes are simply GC running.

Comment: Okay, so that is the test player (`Capabilitites.playerType="External"`) which doesn't correctly represent the actual performance you will get in a regular Flash Player. Test it in your actual target environment (probably browser plugin or standalone player). And I'm sorry to ask again, but you still haven't posted the code that produces these results, afaik.

Comment: I agree with @Botmaster. Lag spikes are often related to garbage collection. Lots of trace() calls can also slow things down. But we don't know what else your code is doing because you haven't posted it, so we are just guessing.

Comment: @Aaron. I copied all the lines of dt output and pasted them in this post.

Comment: Right, but your problem isn't the output, it's the cause of the output. Show us all the code you've got in the SWF that produces that output. So far you've only showed the code that measures the frame times. Also, I upvoted CPOCO's answer, you should see what Adobe Scout reveals about those laggy frames. We're all just making blind guesses in the dark at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Adobe Scout** to troubleshoot performance issues. It's a free one-stop-shop for this kind of ordeal. It exactly maps out what components, and how long they are taking up computing resources inside each frame.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to 30fps.

Not sure if the below will help make a difference to the performance. but try doing as:

```
var now = 0;
var then = 0;
var dt = 0;
stage.addEventListener(
    Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
    function(e:Event):void
    {
        now = getTimer();
        dt = now-then;
        //trace(dt);
        then = now;
    }
);
```

Comment: At 30fps the doesn't look smooth at all. Maybe not because of lag spikes, but because of the lack of FPS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all 100fps is a very high frame rate.
As you can see it is never able to reach the desired fps.

You should go for a lower frame rate that is actually reached and not something over the top.
A lot of games use 60, but 30 is also common.

As you experienced yourself: a frame rate is not stable.
As soon as you do anything, calculations have to be made which may or may not take longer than one frame to calculate which results in a lag.

The solution is what you do in your question: make your game based on a time difference between frames.
If 3 ms passed since the last frame, calculate what state your game should be in after 3ms. If a different time passed, say 5ms, use that and so on.

This allows the game to run with a consistent speed, even though the update of the display lags behind.

Comment: It isn't stable at 60 or 30 FPS either. I find it extremely weird that the framerate is unstable even with no calculations. How laggy will it be when I actually do something? Regarding the moving square, I tried multiplying its speed with dt. Which maybe does make it a bit smoother, but I still woudn't call its movement smooth.